# Nested database transactions in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, transaction

I have found the code that uses database transaction (`\Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule::saveStoreLabels`):

```
public function saveStoreLabels($ruleId, $labels)
{
    ...
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    ...
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    try {
        ...
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $connection->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
    $connection->commit();

    return $this;
}
```

I want to get nested transactions where inner transaction should be processed silently (without exception) and outer transaction should be committed if no error occured (even inner transaction is rolled back):

```
public function someOtherMethod(...)
{
    ...
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    ...
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    try {
        ...
        /* nested transaction should be committed or rolled back without exception */
        $connection->beginTransaction();
        try {
            ...
            $connection->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $connection->rollback();
        }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $connection->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
    /* outer transaction should be committed if exception was not thrown */
    $connection->commit();

    return $this;
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, Mysql does not [support nesting transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/implicit-commit.html).

You can emulate this behavior by:

- using [savepoint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/savepoint.html)
- using different connections for inner and outer operation